# Delegate GMSMapView second time

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7, google-maps-sdk-ios

My map works fine only at first time. This is how I declare it.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, GMSMapViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var GoogleMap: GMSMapView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.GoogleMap.delegate = self
        let camera: GMSCameraPosition = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(55.755826, longitude: 37.6173, zoom: 9.0)
        self.GoogleMap?.camera = camera
    }
}
```

When I pass all screens of my app, and get back to the main screen with maps through Segue, all events which are connected to this maps don't work. The map still displays but it stops interacting with other elements on this screen.

I suppose it can be a problem with delegate, but I don't know how to solve it. I would like to hear any suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem. I just didn't define my ViewController variable at the second time. There was incorrect condition.

```
if(vc==nil) {
    vc = self
}
```

So it didn't work second time, cause vc wasn't nil.